# How to replace dictionary particular key value using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing button click to add CollectionView Cell like a Tag UI. Here, I created TagModel class for maintaining TagId and validating each time the tag data available or not by using `if items.contains(tag) == false {….}` (It will avoid duplication into collection view). Now, I need to add one more validation into this, `if items.contains(tag) == true` need to check tagName and current selected values are same. if not same I need to replace that tag value. How to achieve this?

**Tag Validation Code**

```
func tagValidation(){

        // Validate A
        if let aValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "a") as? [String:Any] {
            let tag = TagModel(dict: aValue)
            if items.contains(tag) == false { // how to check if true need to validate current value and already exists values are same. if same no need to replace or else need to replace value
                items.append(tag)
            }
        }
}
```

**First ViewController**

```
@IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let tag = TagModel(tagId: 0, tagName: "test", tagStoreKey: "a")
        tag.save()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking, you talk about a dictionary but in your code you use an array? Also what do you mean by "current selected values"?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `if items.contains(tag) == false || items.first(where: { $0.tagName == tag.tagName }) == nil {
                items.append(tag)
            }`Here, I need to avoid duplication of adding. only one tag I need to add also next time if i call that `tagValidation()`function need to check already exist value same or not. If same no need to replace index value otherwise need to replace value without adding new tag.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, it's probably better if you edit your question to clarify rather than trying to explain the logic in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not right with your equality operator: you are asking if two items are the same - and if they are the same then check if something in them is different :)

Try to search array with **first** method: if you find (and you will) any item matching the case continue with your work.

Something like this:

```
if let aValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "a") as? [String:Any] {
    let tag = TagModel(dict: aValue)
    if items.contains(tag) == false { 
        items.append(tag)
    } else if let existing = items.first(where: { $0 == tag}), existing.tagName != tag.tagName {
        // replace item
        let index = items.firstIndex(of: tag)!
        items[index] = tag
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer!